# Why Include() not available when Single() is used in entity framework code first fluent api

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, eager-loading, ef-fluent-api

I wonder why Include() cannot be used after Single() in eager-loading. For example, in the following snippet, Include is not available:

```
db.Teachers.Single(p => p.Id == currUserId)
           .Include(t => t.OfferedCourses)
           .RegisteredCourses
           .ToList();
```

However, it would work if I have Single() just after Include():

```
db.Teachers.Include(t => t.OfferedCourses)
           .Single(p => p.Id == currUserId)               
           .RegisteredCourses
           .ToList();
```

This way, many unnecessary related data will be returned. The following is the method I ended up with:

```
 db.Teachers.Where(p => p.Id == currUserId)
            .Include(t => t.OfferedCourses)
            .First()
            .RegisteredCourses
            .ToList();
```

Is this the only solution?

Comment: `.Include()` is a valid extension method for type `IQueryable`.  When you specify `db.Teachers.Include(` or `db.Teacher.Where( p => p.Id == curreUserId )` you are correctly satifying this requirement because both `db.Teachers` and `db.Teachers.Where()` return type `IQueryable`.  Are you certain that your second example is 'overquerying'?  At first glance, this should be ok.

Comment: after `Single()` I only get the properties of Teacher entity, I think `Single()` convert the result into a single Teacher entity.

Comment: That is correct -- `Single()` returns a single instance of the entity type.  BTW -- your data model is not obvious from the posted code.  It appears like you are querying for a `Teacher` whose `Id` matches the value of `currUserId`.  While I can imagine a use case where the teacher is the one signed in (i.e. `currUserId`) you then reference `RegisteredCourses` which seems like a student attribute -- but again I can imagine a structure where `Teacher` has `RegisteredCourses`.  Can you use pseudo-code or english to describe what you are trying to retrieve with this query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an answer to your question from the title of the post:

> Why Include() not available when Single() is used in entity framework code first fluent api

`.Include()` is an extension method in Linq-To-Entities that expects type `IQueryable`.

When you specify `db.Teachers.Include()` or `db.Teacher.Where().Include()` you are satisfying this requirement because both `db.Teachers` and `db.Teachers.Where()` return type `IQueryable`.

But when you specify `db.Teachers.Single()` that returns type `Teacher` which won't work for the use of `Include()`.